# Password Expiration on Drupal or Ldap side?

Tags: drupal, ldap

So I am working with drupal and all the users are also connected to ldap. I want to know whats the best way to implement a password expiration for users who have had a password for X amount of time. Is there a way to achieve this solely through ldap or must we have a module accomplish this task through drupal side?

Answer (score 0):

Password expiration is easily enforced by the LDAP server.  With OpenLDAP look at the [ppolicy overlay](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/overlays.html).  With [OpenDJ](https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/opendj/2.6/admin-guide#chap-pwd-policy) just start up dsconfig and let the menus guide you.  [Apache Directory Server](http://directory.apache.org/apacheds/advanced-ug/4.3-password-policy.html) has it as well as [Fedora/389](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_directory_server/9.0/html/administration_guide/user_account_management#User_Account_Management-Managing_the_Password_Policy).  What's your LDAP server again?

You'll need drupal to analyze LDAP response messages when a password policy kicks in.  I'm no drupal user myself, so I don't know how well this is supported.